# What does ServletResponse#flushBuffer() cover?

Tags: java, servlets, response, flush

If I call [`ServletResponse.flushBuffer()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#flushBuffer()),

do I need to call [`ServletResponse.getOutputStream().close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream())

**and/or** [`ServletResponse.getOutputStream().flush()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream())

(same for [`ServletResponse.getWriter().close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter())

and/or [`ServletResponse.getWriter().flush()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter())) ?

Comment: This doesn't feel right... Wouldn't you get your writer at the beginning, hold it in a member variable while you are doing your thing, and then call flush and close on the member variable when you're done?

Comment: You can use one or the other, no need for both. If you use the OutputStream, you should close it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Actually, I'm using `IOUtils.copyLarge(myInputStream, response.getOutputStream());`. The question is, will `response.flushBuffer()` automatically close the inner stream?

Comment: Tomcat has a method [Response#finishResponse](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/Response.html#finishResponse()) which takes care of closing the response stream. You need to close the ones you make.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both `flush()` and `close()` are completely different methods:

### flush() ...

The    `flush()` method is used to flush the buffered response to the client. It will also lead to commit the response headers.

By default Server container will automatically call this if the internal buffer is reached.

You should call explicitly if you want to send the response in custom chunks.

### close() ...

The `close()` method is used to close the response stream such that no more data can be written.

By default Server container will automatically call this at the end of Servlet life cycle.

You should call explicitly if you do not want to allow writing response beyond any point. Attempting to do so will throw an IOException.

Comment: And so? Which one should be called or not?

Comment: Updated my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: I can't see the partial response in the Network tab. It only shows a single request with complete response. How can I validate this on the client side?